How to change the clothes color of a JavaScript modal dynamically based on user selection?
I'm building a fashion stylist app in react naitve, and I want to add a feature where, when a user clicks on a specific color, the clothes  color of a JavaScript modal changes dynamically. This would allow users to visualize how different colors look in real time.
I have no idea where to start with implementing this. Could someone guide me on how to achieve this functionality using JavaScript and react native?

HTML5 offers a modal system using the <dialog> tag with the js .showModal() method

they're using react native

You can create an SVG for cloth, and pass the color value to the SVG. As an example consider below.
import React from 'react';
import { Svg, Path } from 'react-native-svg';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const ShirtSVG = ({ color = 'green' }) => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        {/* Shirt body */}
            <Path d="M60 20 L80 20 L100 50 L120 20 L140 20 L160 50 L150 140 L50 140 L40 50 Z"
            fill={color}
            stroke="#000"
            strokeWidth="2"
       />
       {/* Collar */}
       <Path
           d="M80 20 L100 50 L120 20"
           fill="#fff"
           stroke="#000"
           strokeWidth="2"
       />
       {/* Left sleeve */}
       <Path
           d="M60 20 L40 50 L50 60 L65 45"
           fill={color}
           stroke="#000"
           strokeWidth="2"
       />
       {/* Right sleeve */}
       <Path
           d="M140 20 L160 50 L150 60 L135 45"
           fill={color}
           stroke="#000"
           strokeWidth="2"
       />
    </Svg>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 1,
   },
});

export default ShirtSVG;

